# Acro only prints final entry for one class

Tags: symbols, thesis, nomenclature, acro

I'm trying to print all acronyms defined through `\DeclareAcronym` (not just the ones mentioned in the full paper), but only the last acronym in the nomenclature section is printed (regardless of which one it is). Why might this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Here's my acro include in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[]{acro}           % to make acronym/symbol glossary
\acsetup{}
\acuseall
```

My `symbols-page.tex`:

```
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
```

In my `symbols.tex`:

```
% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{crf}{
  short = CRF ,
  long  = conditional random field ,
  class = abbrev
}

...

\DeclareAcronym{voi}{
  short = VOI ,
  long  = value of information ,
  class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{dmtsp}{
  short = DMTSP ,
  long  = dynamic multi-target search problem ,
  class = abbrev
}


% class `nomencl': nomenclature

\DeclareAcronym{k}{
  short = $k$ ,
  long  = Discrete time index ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}

...

\DeclareAcronym{X_k}{
  short = $X_k$ ,
  long  = $n$-dimensional vector of state variables at time $k$ ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}

\DeclareAcronym{D_k}{
  short = $D_k$ ,
  long  = Random variable of softmax class selected at time $k$ ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your acronyms of the class nomenclature all have the field `sort  = a`. Apparently, this field must have a unique value, otherwise the second entry will overwrite the first, and the third entry will overwrite the second one. Either delete the `sort`-fields, or change them to something like this:

```
\DeclareAcronym{k}{
  short = $k$ ,
  long  = Discrete time index ,
  sort  = a ,
  class = nomencl
}

\DeclareAcronym{X_k}{
  short = $X_k$ ,
  long  = $n$-dimensional vector of state variables at time $k$ ,
  sort  = b ,
  class = nomencl
}

\DeclareAcronym{D_k}{
  short = $D_k$ ,
  long  = Random variable of softmax class selected at time $k$ ,
  sort  = c ,
  class = nomencl
}
```

Comment: You're right that this happens but it really shouldn't. I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

This erroneous behaviour is fixed in v2.6:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}[2016/07/20] % v2.6 or newer
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = f ,
  long  = foo ,
  sort = a
}
\DeclareAcronym{bar}{
  short = b ,
  long  = bar ,
  sort = d
}
\DeclareAcronym{baz}{
  short = bz ,
  long  = baz ,
  sort = a
}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]